# Gap appearing in my layout between img and p

Tags: html, css

It must be something simple I am missing, but for the life of me can't figure it out.  There is a small gap between the `<img>` and the `<p>` but I have zero margins so I don't know what it is - Can some kind soul come to my assistance?

CSS

```
.PlaceCard   { width: 100%; height: auto; }
.PlaceCard a { width: 100%; height: 100%; background:white; display: block; 
               -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
               -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; 
                border: 1px solid #bbb;  }
.PlaceCard img, .PlaceCard p  { background:#03F; width: 100%; height:auto; 
                                padding:5px; margin:0;  
                                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
                                -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
                                box-sizing: border-box; 
                                border: 0px solid #bbb; }
.PlaceCard a:hover { background:#0F3;}
.PlaceCard p img { display:inline-block; padding:0; padding-right:10px; 
                   float:left; max-width:50px; max-height:50px; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="PlaceCard"><a href="Cost-of-Living-in-Goa-India.htm">
    <img src="Images/Cost-Of-Living.jpg" alt="Cost of Living India Goa" 
         width="375" height="300">
        <p>
             <img src="Images/Google.png" width="60" height="60" alt=""/>
             Cost Of Living<br>(GOA)
        </p>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You have set a 5 pixel padding for img and p tags.

Comment: @Juhana No, it's not about padding. It's white spaces. Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/LJrME/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an expected behavior of inline/inline-block elements (image in your case), they respect white spaces including line breaks. So you see them. As a simple fix, you can try to define display as block:

```
.PlaceCard img, .PlaceCard p {
    ...
    display: block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LJrME/

Comment: I knew it would be something simple - Thank you! Works a treat